# Delete data which is in date range 2016 to 2015 elasticsearch 1.6

Tags: elasticsearch

data request which is created in 2015 and 2016 are processed in 2017.So, these are in 2017 indices data. I want to delete these date based on creation date. I'm unable to do this. Below is the query I'm using.

> 

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://host:port/logging_2017*/_query' -d '{
>   "query": {
>     "match": {
>       "actionType": {
>         "query": "update_device_space",
>         "type": "boolean",
>         "operator": "AND"
>       }
>     }
>   },
>   "filter": {
>     "range": {
>       "requestedAt": {
>         "gte": "1420070400000",
>         "lte": "1483228799000"
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }'
```

What I have to do. Please help me

Comment: As far as I can see, you're not using the [delete by query endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/docs-delete-by-query.html)

Comment: Thanks, @Val. While posting the command lost some of the parameters and have modified the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to do this by below curl command. Along with date range, if we want to add another condition, we can do it by using **term**

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://host:port/logging_*/_query' -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "range": {
              "requestedAt": {
                "gte": 1420070400000,
                "lte": 1483228799000
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "field": "value"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}'
```